# How to install Pig plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, apache-pig

I'm about to start working with Apache Pig in Ubuntu, and was looking for best pig plugins and  quick installation guide to start with a sample PIG script in Eclipse.I have googled a lot but could not find the proper description of how to install pig plugin in eclipse. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What does Eclipse provide for writing Pig? Auto-complete? Seems somewhat unnecessary... what is wrong with a simple text-editor?

Comment: @cricket_007: To get some syntax highlighting and auto complete. I want to find out a way of executing the pig script in eclipse as well.

Comment: This doesn't help? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/How+to+set+up+Eclipse+environment (and aside: I find Spark to be a better tool than Pig, in most scenarios)

Comment: You can try from this https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/PigTools

Comment: @krishnaChaitanyReddy: I have already verified the link that you have shared which has the info of the plugins but not how to get started by executing a sample script.

Comment: Did you try to follow this? https://abhijitsureshshingate.wordpress.com/2013/07/08/code-debug-test-apache-pig-scripts-using-eclipse-on-windows/

Answer (score 0):

Idk about the plugin, but for the script execution you can use following simple code

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("pig.splitCombination", "false");
// any other properties you need
PigServer pigServer = new PigServer("local", props);
pigServer.debugOn();
pigServer.registerScript("testdata/test.pig");
```

You'll also need to specify

```
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
         <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
         <version>1.2.1</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.pig</groupId>
         <artifactId>pig</artifactId>
         <version>0.14.0</version>
     </dependency>
```

in your POM file.